# paypal express and credit cards or guest account

Tags: credit-card, paypal

We have set PayPal express and done the code changes to allow Pay by Credit card without logging into PayPal. SOLUTIONTYPE=Sole and LANDINGPAGE=Billing and PayPal Account Optional are set to on.

The PayPal checkout screen (either enhanced or classic view) show create an account. In both landing pages the label implies you are creating a new PayPal account not going to the pay with credit card option. But once you click on the icon the next screen is, in fact, the pay with credit card option.

Current look: 
https://i.stack.imgur.com/iwhxP.jpg (I clicked on the arrow to open the view and though it says Create a PP account its the fill in the cc information page)  On the classic view the button also says Create an Account and when you click the CC page opens up.

How do I get the screen to look like either one of these that say: Pay with debit or credit card https://i.stack.imgur.com/yr15U.jpg   or me have seen buy as a guest in other screens also.

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you're using a recent API version number (current version is 120.0 I believe) and then add the follow parameter to your SetExpressCheckout request.

USERSELECTEDFUNDINGSOURCE=CreditCard

That should give you what you're after.